# How to detect the presence of URL in a string

Tags: java, url

I have an input String say `Please go to http://stackoverflow.com`. The url part of the String is detected and an anchor `<a href=""></a>` is automatically added by many browser/IDE/applications. So it becomes `Please go to <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>http://stackoverflow.com</a>`.

I need to do the same using Java.

Answer (score 61):

### Use java.net.URL for that!!

Hey, why don't use the core class in java for this "java.net.URL" and let it validate the URL.

While the following code violates the golden principle "Use exception for exceptional conditions only" it does not make sense to me to try to reinvent the wheel for something that is veeery mature on the java platform.

Here's the code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

// Replaces URLs with html hrefs codes
public class URLInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        // separate input by spaces ( URLs don't have spaces )
        String [] parts = s.split("\\s+");

        // Attempt to convert each item into an URL.   
        for( String item : parts ) try {
            URL url = new URL(item);
            // If possible then replace with anchor...
            System.out.print("<a href=\"" + url + "\">"+ url + "</a> " );    
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // If there was an URL that was not it!...
            System.out.print( item + " " );
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Using the following input:

```
"Please go to http://stackoverflow.com and then mailto:oscarreyes@wordpress.com to download a file from    ftp://user:pass@someserver/someFile.txt"
```

Produces the following output:

```
Please go to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> and then <a href="mailto:oscarreyes@wordpress.com">mailto:oscarreyes@wordpress.com</a> to download a file from    <a href="ftp://user:pass@someserver/someFile.txt">ftp://user:pass@someserver/someFile.txt</a>
```

Of course different protocols could be handled in different ways.
You can get all the info with the getters of URL class, for instance

```
 url.getProtocol();
```

Or the rest of the attributes: spec, port, file, query, ref etc. etc

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Handles all the protocols ( at least all of those the java platform is aware ) and as an extra benefit, if there is any URL that java currently does not recognize and eventually gets incorporated into the URL class ( by library updating ) you'll get it transparently!

Comment: I like this over Jeff Atwoods article specifically for java, as you don't have to deal with the regex at all. But his article *does* have good points about URLs often being embedded in things like parentheses. A combination would work really well.

Comment: You should at least split on characters not found on URLs: you often see URLs between angle brackets (precisely because they don't have the inconveniences of parentheses). But good idea.

Comment: I have just know, the URL class is broken:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDN_EYUvUq0

Comment: A small change is needed on this. In my app I am using your algorithm to parse a links out of twitter messages. In one case the string ":-)" is a valid string so you try to create a URL. Instead of throwing MalformedUrlException it throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Odd edge case of the Url class. Add a catch for this and the bug is fixed.

Comment: What VM gave you a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?  It works with Sun's JDK 1.6.0_31, 1.6.0_26 and 1.5.0_22.

Comment: Very nice, I have used your answer and did this for me http://paste2.org/p/2061276 thanks.

Comment: TL;DW version of _URL class is broken_ video, use URI instead.

Comment: @MKJParekh check out my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12330748/318174 . It actually handles many of the "Atwood" problems.

Answer (score 14):

While it's not Java specific, Jeff Atwood recently posted an article about the pitfalls you might run into when trying to locate and match URLs in arbitrary text:

[The Problem With URLs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/)

It gives a good regex that can be used along with the snippet of code that you need to use to properly (more or less) handle parens.

The regex:

```
\(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]
```

The paren cleanup:

```
if (s.StartsWith("(") && s.EndsWith(")"))
{
    return s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Correct URL of Jeff Atwoods blog post: [The Problem With URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html)

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this (adjust the regex to suit your needs):

```
String originalString = "Please go to http://www.stackoverflow.com";
String newString = originalString.replaceAll("http://.+?(com|net|org)/{0,1}", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code makes these modifications to the "Atwood Approach":

1. Detects https in addition to http (adding other schemes is trivial)
2. The CASE_INSENSTIVE flag is used since HtTpS:// is valid.
3. Matching sets of parentheses are peeled off (they can be nested to
   any level).  Further, any remaining unmatched left parentheses are
   stripped, but trailing right parentheses are left intact (to respect
   wikipedia-style URLs)
4. The URL is HTML Encoded in the link text.
5. The target attribute is passed in via method parameter.  Other attributes can be added as desired.
6. It does not use \b to identify a word break before matching a URL.  URLs can begin with a left parenthesis or http[s]:// with no other requirement.

Notes:

- Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils are used in the code below
- The call to HtmlUtil.encode() below is a util which ultimately calls
  some Tomahawk code to HTML-encode the link text, but any similar utility will do.
- See the method comment for a usage in JSF or other environments where output is HTML Encoded by default.

This was written in response to our client's requirements and we feel it represents a reasonable compromise between the allowable characters from the RFC and common usage.  It is offered here in the hopes that it will be useful to others.

Further expansion could be made which would allow for any Unicode characters to be entered (i.e. not escaped with %XX (two digit hex) and hyperlinked, but that would require accepting all Unicode letters plus limited punctuation and then splitting on the "acceptable" delimiters (eg. .,%,|,#, etc.), URL-encoding each part and then gluing back together.  For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Björn_Andrésen (which the Stack Overflow generator does not detect) would be "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rn_Andr%C3%A9sen" in the href, but would contain Björn_Andrésen in the linked text on the page.

```
// NOTES:   1) \w includes 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _
//          2) The leading '-' is the '-' character. It must go first in character class expression
private static final String VALID_CHARS = "-\\w+&@#/%=~()|";
private static final String VALID_NON_TERMINAL = "?!:,.;";

// Notes on the expression:
//  1) Any number of leading '(' (left parenthesis) accepted.  Will be dealt with.  
//  2) s? ==> the s is optional so either [http, https] accepted as scheme
//  3) All valid chars accepted and then one or more
//  4) Case insensitive so that the scheme can be hTtPs (for example) if desired
private static final Pattern URI_FINDER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\(*https?://["+ VALID_CHARS + VALID_NON_TERMINAL + "]*[" +VALID_CHARS + "]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );

/**
 * <p>
 * Finds all "URL"s in the given _rawText, wraps them in 
 * HTML link tags and returns the result (with the rest of the text
 * html encoded).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * We employ the procedure described at:
 * http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html
 * which is a <b>must-read</b>.
 * </p>
 * Basically, we allow any number of left parenthesis (which will get stripped away)
 * followed by http:// or https://.  Then any number of permitted URL characters
 * (based on http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) followed by a single character
 * of that set (basically, those minus typical punctuation).  We remove all sets of 
 * matching left & right parentheses which surround the URL.
 *</p>
 * <p>
 * This method *must* be called from a tag/component which will NOT
 * end up escaping the output.  For example:
 * <PRE>
 * <h:outputText ... escape="false" value="#{core:hyperlinkText(textThatMayHaveURLs, '_blank')}"/>
 * </pre>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Reason: we are adding <code>&lt;a href="..."&gt;</code> tags to the output *and*
 * encoding the rest of the string.  So, encoding the outupt will result in
 * double-encoding data which was already encoded - and encoding the <code>a href</code>
 * (which will render it useless).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * 
 * @param   _rawText  - if <code>null</code>, returns <code>""</code> (empty string).
 * @param   _target   - if not <code>null</code> or <code>""</code>, adds a target attributed to the generated link, using _target as the attribute value.
 */
public static final String hyperlinkText( final String _rawText, final String _target ) {

    String returnValue = null;

    if ( !StringUtils.isBlank( _rawText ) ) {

        final Matcher matcher = URI_FINDER_PATTERN.matcher( _rawText );

        if ( matcher.find() ) {

            final int originalLength    =   _rawText.length();

            final String targetText = ( StringUtils.isBlank( _target ) ) ? "" :  " target=\"" + _target.trim() + "\"";
            final int targetLength      =   targetText.length();

            // Counted 15 characters aside from the target + 2 of the URL (max if the whole string is URL)
            // Rough guess, but should keep us from expanding the Builder too many times.
            final StringBuilder returnBuffer = new StringBuilder( originalLength * 2 + targetLength + 15 );

            int currentStart;
            int currentEnd;
            int lastEnd     = 0;

            String currentURL;

            do {
                currentStart = matcher.start();
                currentEnd = matcher.end();
                currentURL = matcher.group();

                // Adjust for URLs wrapped in ()'s ... move start/end markers
                //      and substring the _rawText for new URL value.
                while ( currentURL.startsWith( "(" ) && currentURL.endsWith( ")" ) ) {
                    currentStart = currentStart + 1;
                    currentEnd = currentEnd - 1;

                    currentURL = _rawText.substring( currentStart, currentEnd );
                }

                while ( currentURL.startsWith( "(" ) ) {
                    currentStart = currentStart + 1;

                    currentURL = _rawText.substring( currentStart, currentEnd );
                }

                // Text since last match
                returnBuffer.append( HtmlUtil.encode( _rawText.substring( lastEnd, currentStart ) ) );

                // Wrap matched URL
                returnBuffer.append( "<a href=\"" + currentURL + "\"" + targetText + ">" + currentURL + "</a>" );

                lastEnd = currentEnd;

            } while ( matcher.find() );

            if ( lastEnd < originalLength ) {
                returnBuffer.append( HtmlUtil.encode( _rawText.substring( lastEnd ) ) );
            }

            returnValue = returnBuffer.toString();
        }
    } 

    if ( returnValue == null ) {
        returnValue = HtmlUtil.encode( _rawText );
    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive:

```
String msg = "Please go to http://stackoverflow.com";
String withURL = msg.replaceAll("(?:https?|ftps?)://[\\w/%.-]+", "<a href='$0'>$0</a>");
System.out.println(withURL);
```

This needs refinement, to match proper URLs, and particularly GET parameters (?foo=bar&x=25)

Answer (score 0):

Your are asking two separate questions.

1. What is the best way to identify URLs in Strings?
   See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)
2. How to code the above solution in Java? other responses illustrating `String.replaceAll` usage have addressed this

Answer (score 0):

A good refinement to PhiLho's answer would be:
`msg.replaceAll("(?:https?|ftps?)://[\w/%.-][/\??\w=?\w?/%.-]?[/\?&\w=?\w?/%.-]*", "$0");`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own URI/URL extractor and figured someone might find it useful considering it IMHO is better than the other answers because:

- Its Stream based and can be used on large documents
- Its extendable to handle all kinds of ["Atwood Paren"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/) problems through a strategy chain.

Since the code is somewhat long for a post (albeit only one Java file) I have put it on [**gist github**](https://gist.github.com/3674391).

Here is a signature of one of the main methods to call it to show how its the above bullet points:

```
public static Iterator<ExtractedURI> extractURIs(
    final Reader reader,
    final Iterable<ToURIStrategy> strategies,
    String ... schemes);
```

There is a default strategy chain which handle most of the Atwood problems.

```
public static List<ToURIStrategy> DEFAULT_STRATEGY_CHAIN = ImmutableList.of(
    new RemoveSurroundsWithToURIStrategy("'"),
    new RemoveSurroundsWithToURIStrategy("\""),
    new RemoveSurroundsWithToURIStrategy("(", ")"),
    new RemoveEndsWithToURIStrategy("."),
    DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
    REMOVE_LAST_STRATEGY);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Your solution might be great but it requires some more explanation. I have no reader and no array of schemes and dont know what is it used for. I just want to convert a string value.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small library which does exactly this:

https://github.com/robinst/autolink-java

Some tricky examples and the links that it detects:

- `http://example.com.` → http://example.com.
- `http://example.com,` → http://example.com,
- `(http://example.com)` → (http://example.com)
- `(... (see http://example.com))` → (... (see http://example.com))
- `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda)` →
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda)
- `http://üñîçøðé.com/` → [http://üñîçøðé.com/](http://example.com)

Comment: Any plans for this to support urls that don't begin with http/https e.g. www.test.com?

Comment: @mark Not currently, but I'm open to pull request. It could be added as an optional feature.

Comment: Look like this library is no longer supported in 2022.

Comment: @levacjeep What makes you say that?

Comment: Last commit was Feb 2021 and last release was in 2018. I personally wouldn't use such a project in an enterprise production application.

Comment: @levacjeep Would you look at that, there's new commits now and a new release!

Comment: @robinst haha nice! I'll take a look :).

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static List<String> extractURL(String text) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile(
                    "(http://|https://){1}[\\w\\.\\-/:\\#\\?\\=\\&\\;\\%\\~\\+]+",
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Suggesting a more convenient way of doing it in 2017:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

or `android:autoLink="all"` for all kinds of links.

Answer (score -4):

To detect an URL you just need this:

```
if (yourtextview.getText().toString().contains("www") || yourtextview.getText().toString().contains("http://"){ your code here if contains URL;}
```

Comment: *youtube.com* is a perfectly recognizable url as far as user experience is concerned.