# Determine if string is a URL with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, url, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)
>   [Java-How to detect the presence of URL in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/java-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Is there a way to see if a string is a valid URL? I'm using MIDP library and there are not regular expressions in MIDP. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please search the site before posting, "java regex url" returns plenty of valid information.

Comment: Note that searching "java regex url" would direct you to use a regex to detect a URL, when the better solution would be missed:  construct a java.net.URL from the string.

Comment: If everything is an exact duplicate, then why bother answering any question on SO?

Comment: Java.net is not a library in java mobile edition. J2ME doesn't not have Java.Net library, neither does it support regex or String.replaceAll

Comment: @Edwin: that's suggested in the top answers to such questions.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know about the lack of URL support in JavaME.  I'll ammend my answer for the ME crowd, after I construct a better one.

Comment: @Mat, perhaps it is, but that's because it's an obvious answer.  I'll bet that you and I can come up with independent answers to x + 4 = 5 without need for copying from each other; but, if only the first poster gets to benefit from such a task, then there's no reason to answer anything with an archive like SO's.

Comment: @Edwin: I'm only pointing out the fact that by typing the first three tags from this person's question in the search box, there was a wealth of info already available. if none of that is relevant to the OP, then his question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just construct a `java.net.URL` out of the string and catch any exceptions that might be thrown?

```
String something;
try {
  URL url = new URL(something);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  // it wasn't a URL
}
```

Comment: is it also required to call .toURI() ?

Comment: @Gaurav Only if you need a URI type.  If all you need is a URL, then creating the URL will do.  Note that it's not a good idea to create a URI if you need a URL, because URIs contain all URLs and other element (URNs, for example) and anyone that built a URN might break code that assumes URIs are just URLs.  Note that this only validates the format, but that's all that can be validated until the URL is used.