# How can I detect if a string contains a URL in java?

Tags: java, android, string, token, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java-How to detect the presence of URL in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/java-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Let's assume I have the string:

"I like visiting http://www.google.com and www.apple.com"

How can I tokenize this string, and determine if the token contains a URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

// Replaces URLs with html hrefs codes
public class URLInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        // separete input by spaces ( URLs don't have spaces )
        String [] parts = s.split("\\s");

        // Attempt to convert each item into an URL.   
        for( String item : parts ) try {
            URL url = new URL(item);
            // If possible then replace with anchor...
            System.out.print("<a href=\"" + url + "\">"+ url + "</a> " );    
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // If there was an URL that was not it!...
            System.out.print( item + " " );
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Obtained from, [How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/java-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)