# substring between two delimiters

Tags: java, split, substring

I have a string as : "This is a URL http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used"

I just need to extract the URL that is starting from http and ending at pdf :
http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf

```
String sLeftDelimiter = "http://";
String[] tempURL = sValueFromAddAtt.split(sLeftDelimiter );
String sRequiredURL = sLeftDelimiter + tempURL[1];
```

This gives me the output as "http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used"

Need help on this.

Comment: Related to this question, please check it out:

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This kind of problem is what regular expressions were made for:

```
Pattern findUrl = Pattern.compile("\\bhttp.*?\\.pdf\\b");
Matcher matcher = findUrl.matcher("This is a URL http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used");
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The regular expression explained:

- `\b` before the "http" there is a word boundary (i.e. xhttp does not match)
- `http` the string "http" (be aware that this also matches "https" and "httpsomething")
- `.*?` any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`), but try to use the least amount of characters (`?`)
- `\.pdf` the literal string ".pdf"
- `\b` after the ".pdf" there is a word boundary (i.e. .pdfoo does not match)

If you would like to match only http and https, try to use this instead of `http` in your string:

- `https?\:` - this matches the string http, then an optional "s" (indicated by the `?` after the s) and then a colon.

Comment: Thanks a lot..this one really helped...as the text before after the url can be anything , so this regex for extracting the URL is what i needed.

Comment: If you want to support arbitrary strings that are either URLs or strings that look like URLs but don't have a protocol handler (e.g. www.foo.com), then use Gruber's regular expression http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: Thanks for crisp answer ....I used as :     
Pattern findUrl = Pattern.compile("\\bversion-.*?\\.0.0\\b");
Matcher matcher = findUrl.matcher(response.toString());
            if (matcher.find()) {
                
                System.out.println(matcher.group().substring(10,13)); // to get the substring
            }

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use **startsWith("http://")** and **endsWith(".pdf")** mthods of String class.

Both the method returns **boolean** value, if both returns **true**, then your condition succeed else your condition is failed.

Comment: The question states that he has a string which contains "This is a URL `URL` which should be used". I don't see how `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` are applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String StringName="This is a URL http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used";

StringName=StringName.substring(StringName.indexOf("http:"),StringName.indexOf("which"));
```

Comment: 'which' may appear several times and before 'http:'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regular Expression` power for here. 
First you have to find `Url` in original string then remove other part.

Following code shows my suggestion:

```
    String regex = "\\b(http|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
    String str = "This is a URL http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used";

    String[] splited = str.split(regex);

    for(String current_part : splited)
    {
        str = str.replace(current_part, "");
    }

    System.out.println(str);
```

This snippet code cans retrieve any url in any string with any pattern.
You cant add customize protocol such as `https` to protocol part in above regular expression.

I hope my answer help you ;)

Comment: Please note that this pattern does not match internationalized domain names such as http://مثال.إختبار

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getStringBetweenStrings(String aString, String aPattern1, String aPattern2) {
    String ret = null;
    int pos1,pos2;

    pos1 = aString.indexOf(aPattern1) + aPattern1.length();
    pos2 = aString.indexOf(aPattern2);

    if ((pos1>0) && (pos2>0) && (pos2 > pos1)) {
        return aString.substring(pos1, pos2);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.replaceAll with a capturing group and back reference for a very concise solution:

```
String input = "This is a URL http://www.google.com/MyDoc.pdf which should be used";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".*(http.*?\\.pdf).*", "$1"));
```

Here's a breakdown for the regex: https://regexr.com/3qmus