# How to extract a string between two delimiters

Tags: java, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [substring between two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171015/substring-between-two-delimiters)

I have a string like

> "ABC[ This is to extract ]"

I want to extract the part `"This is to extract"` in java. I am trying to use split, but it is not working the way I want. Does anyone have suggestion?

Comment: try using [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to know why what you're doing isn't working without seeing your code.

Comment: use StringTokenizer("delimeter","String")

Comment: String bar = StringUtils.substringBetween("ABC[ This is to extract ]", "[", "]");
please see the documentation : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you have just a pair of brackets ( `[]` ) in your string, you can use `indexOf()`:

```
String str = "ABC[ This is the text to be extracted ]";    
String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.indexOf("]"));
```

Comment: Functions `indexOf` and `substring` internally iterates over characters. So keep in mind that when you call `srt.substring(str.indexOf, str.indexOf)` original `str` is iterated 3 times. Which may lead to performance problem in large strings.

Comment: indexOf('[') might be a bit faster than indexOf("[")

Answer (score 72):

If there is only 1 occurrence, the answer of ivanovic is the best way I guess. But if there are many occurrences, you should use regexp:

`\[(.*?)\]` this is your pattern. And in each `group(1)` will get you your string.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
    m.group(1); //is your string. do what you want
}
```

Comment: This is what I am trying Pattern somePart = Pattern.compile("\\b[.*?\\b]"); Matcher matcher = somePart.matcher(info);

Comment: See answer to this thread for applying above method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/java-how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex

Answer (score 9):

Try as

```
String s = "ABC[ This is to extract ]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\[ *(.*) *\\].*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        m.find();
        String text = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
  String s = "ABC[This is to extract]";

    System.out.println(s);
    int startIndex = s.indexOf('[');
    System.out.println("indexOf([) = " + startIndex);
    int endIndex = s.indexOf(']');
    System.out.println("indexOf(]) = " + endIndex);
    System.out.println(s.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex));
```