# How to display an image in android ImageView from the <img> tag

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an application which fetches data from a MySQL database. That data contains image urls which I have managed to implement an imageLoader class to display the image using the images url. I have however hit a dead end when it came to displaying an image which is contained in the text fetched and is wrapped in the `<img>` tag. Kindly assist me in displaying an image contained in the post content. Below is a sample of the data fetched.

```
This is a sample post, you may choose to continue reading or not. <a href='http://website.com/post'><img src=' http://website.com/post.jpg'></a>
This is a sample post, you may choose to continue reading or not
```

From the above text, How do I display **http://website.com/post.jpg** in an android imageview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set image from url for imageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview)

Comment: As I stated in my question, I can parse an image from url. What I need to do is get the image from a bunch of text such as the example above in the code tags

Comment: You want the content/value of the src attribute of that img tag? The value is an url. If you have the url you can download the image. After that set it to an image view. It's unclear at which step you need help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796451/how-to-extract-a-string-between-two-delimiters

Comment: What I want to achieve is remove the html tags `<a> and <img> ` and display the image using its url as part of the content just like it appears in a website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a perfect solution for my problem. Using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), I am able to get the HTML tags in my string and also I am able to replace the entire HTML segment with whatever content I want. Thanks for your input and hope this answer will help someone sometime.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is extract the image url from the text returned from the database something like the following will suffice:

```
int start = s.indexOf("<img src='")+10;
int end = s.indexOf("'",start);
String url = s.substring(start, end));
```

where s is the string returned from the database

Comment: Yes, will this also remove the entire image code from the string i.e remove `<a href='some_link'><img src='some_link'></a>` from the string

Comment: No. Is that what you want? Or do you need the two urls in separate strings?

Comment: Nop, I neew to get the image url as above so that I can use it in my image loader and also remove the code block from the text as the reader does need to read it