# how to read only URL from txt file in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a text file having multiple URLs with other information of the URL. How can I read the txt file and save the URLs only in an array to download it? I want to use

```
C = textscan(fileId, formatspec);
```

What should  I mention in `formatspec` for URL as format?

Comment: I am not java savvy but I guess you could do it using java in Matlab, you can start by reading [*How to detect the presence of URL in a string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string) and [*Calling Java from MATLAB*](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/07/06/calling-java-from-matlab/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a job for `textscan`; you should use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this. In MATLAB, regexes are described [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html). 
For URLs, also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) for examples in other languages.

Here's an example in MATLAB:

```
% This string is obtained through textscan or something
str = {...
    'pre-URL garbage http://www.example.com/index.php?query=test&otherStuf=info more stuff here'
    'other foolish stuff ftp://localhost/home/ruler_of_the_world/awesomeContent.py 1 2 3 4 misleading://';
};


% find URLs    
C = regexpi(str, ...
    ['((http|https|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)',...
    '[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]'], 'match');

C{:}
```

Result:

```
ans = 
    'http://www.example.com/index.php?query=test&otherStuf=info'
ans = 
    'ftp://localhost/home/ruler_of_the_world/awesomeContent.py'
```

Note that this regex requires you to have the protocol included, *or* have a leading `www.` or `ftp.`. Something like `example.com/universal_remote.cgi?redirect=` is **NOT** matched.

You could go on and make the regex cover more and more cases. However, eventually you'll stumble upon the the most important conclusion (as made [here](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) for example; where I got my regex from):  given the *full* definition of what precisely constitutes a valid URL, there is no *single* regex able to *always* match *every* valid URL. That is, there are valid URLs you can dream up that are *not* captured by any of the regexes shown.

But please keep in mind that this last statement is more theoretical rather than practical -- those non-matchable URLs are valid but not often encountered in practice :) In other words, if your URLs have a pretty standard form, you're pretty much covered with the regex I gave you.

Now, I fooled around a bit with the Java suggestion by pm89. As I suspected, it is an order of magnitude slower than just a regex, since you introduce another "layer of goo" to the code (in my timings, the difference was about 40x slower, excluding the imports). Here's my version:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

str = {...
    'pre-URL garbage http://www.example.com/index.php?query=test&otherStuf=info more stuff here'
    'pre--URL garbage example.com/index.php?query=test&otherStuf=info more stuff here'
    'other foolish stuff ftp://localhost/home/ruler_of_the_world/awesomeContent.py 1 2 3 4 misleading://';
};


% Attempt to convert each item into an URL.  
for ii = 1:numel(str)    
    cc = textscan(str{ii}, '%s');
    for jj = 1:numel(cc{1})
        try
            url = java.net.URL(cc{1}{jj})

        catch ME
            % rethrow any non-url related errors
            if isempty(regexpi(ME.message, 'MalformedURLException'))
                throw(ME);
            end

        end
    end
end
```

Results:

```
url =
    'http://www.example.com/index.php?query=test&otherStuf=info'
url =
    'ftp://localhost/home/ruler_of_the_world/awesomeContent.py'
```

I'm not too familiar with `java.net.URL`, but apparently, it is also unable to find URLs without leading protocol or standard domain (e.g., `example.com/path/to/page`).

This snippet can undoubtedly be improved upon, but I would urge you to consider why you'd want to do this for this longer, inherently slower and far uglier solution :)

Comment: +1: Nice study and good solution. However I don't think there would be a fast way to detect something without the standard scheme (like `example.com/path/to/page`) since the only way would need a connection to server and check the connectivity as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1600333/1698972) suggests.

Answer (score 3):

As I suspected you could use `java.net.URL` according to [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285880/1698972).

To implement the same code in *Matlab*:

First read the file into a string, using [`fileread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) for example:

```
str = fileread('Sample.txt');
```

Then split the text with respect to spaces, using [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html):

```
spl_str = strsplit(str);
```

Finally use `java.net.URL` to detect the URLs:

```
for k = 1:length(spl_str)
    try
       url = java.net.URL(spl_str{k})
       % Store or save the URL contents here
    catch e
       % it's not a URL.
    end
end
```

You can write the URL contents into a file using [`urlwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlwrite.html). But first convert the URLs obtained from `java.net.URL` to `char`:

```
url = java.net.URL(spl_str{k});
urlwrite(char(url), 'test.html');
```

Hope it helps.