# Open text link in web view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have the text in textview that is "Open the link http://www.google.com to find anything." The text i have set in my class file. SO, when i click on this link. The link is open in browser. I want open this link in my web view. How can i do this? 
My xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="TextView" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="444dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

in your oncreate method,

```
 WebView mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mywebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

And then create a class like,

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("somePartOfYourUniqueUrl")){ 
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(url); // load url in webview
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.net.URL` for this
Here is a link for your help, using this you may parse `url` from given string

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, with WebView, you need to declare a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) object and override the `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` method, there you can filter urls or give some customized functionality.

In your case, to stay on the WebView, you would need to return false on that method.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/05/override-url-loading-in-webview-android-tutorial/).

To handle the click event on the `TextView's` url. As [it's suggested on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) you can filter the `ACTION_VIEW` intent on your WebView containing Activity. If you need [more guidance about intent-filters, check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

For a TextView its a little bit more work, You'll have to make your own copy of the Linkyfy class and use a TransformFilter to make the links behave however you want them to. Check out for an example [Android Linkify class](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java) both web and @mentions all in the same `TextView`