# Making Edittext an address and search bar in one Android Eclipse

Tags: android, search, webview, android-edittext, address-bar

I am trying to make an edittext into both a search bar and address bar. Also I am not sure how to allow the user hit enter on their keyboard to initiate the search instead of manually touching the go button.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use IME actions for your case to allow the user to have a sort of "Go" button which is activated by the enter key.  This page on the official Android guide should help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Actions

To detect a URL, use the built in Java class to do it.  See here: [How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string/285880#285880)

Using those two methods, simply check if the entered text is a URL.  If it is, then use it, otherwise you call your search method passing in the entered text.