# general url pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, url

I need a URL pattern that can recognize all the urls in plain text. Now I have one that is working fine in Java (using Pattern): 
("(@)?(http(s)?://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+(\.\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+)+(/[#&\n\-=?\+\%/\.,\w]+)?")

It recognizes most of the URLs such as:

http://www.aaa.com

https://www.aaa.com

www.aaa.com

aaa.com

www.aaa.com/abcd/asdf?a=12

but it could NOT recognize the URLs with port number like www.aaa.com:8000 or www.aaa.com:8000/asdf

Can any of the regular expression experts help me to solve this problem making the above pattern recognizes URLs with port number?

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string

Comment: You have forgotten about [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), ftp, sftp and much more. Basically, it's a really hard job.

Comment: What do you want to do with the URLs once recognized? Strip them from the input, linkify them as HTML, fetch them from the intarwebz?

Comment: @PhilippReichart, I need to identify all the urls from the message (which is in plain text), and replace them with a hard coded string and count how many links in this message.

Comment: [Using a regular expression to match a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/190405#190405), as listed in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Common Tasks > Validation > Internet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could squeeze in a `(:\d+)?`

```
 # (@)?(http(s)?://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+(\.\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+)+(:\d+)?(/[#&\n\-=?\+\%/\.,\w]+)?
 # "(@)?(http(s)?://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(:\\d+)?(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.,\\w]+)?"

 ( @ )?
 (
      http
      ( s )?
      ://
 )?
 [a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+ 
 ( \. \w [a-zA-Z_0-9\-]+ )+
 ( : \d+ )?
 ( / [#&\n\-=?\+\%/\.,\w]+ )?
```